# why can I ping Yahoo IP but not domain name on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, networking, dns, router

I think I have a DNS issue, and/or router issue.
Edit 05/24/2019
Now on my router, I can ping www.yahoo.com successfully, which means the problem is at the server level.

When I ssh into one of my servers, X, I issue command

```
>wget https://www.gnu.org/software/wget
```

I have wget installed actually, just to test internet connection

I got error like

```
>wget: unable to resolve host address: 'ftp.gnu.org'
```

At the beginning, I thought the issue was due to the firewall. However I found I could ping external IP.

```
user@reporter:/etc/network$ ping 72.30.35.9  #ping Yahoo IP, works
PING 72.30.35.9 (72.30.35.9) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 72.30.35.9: icmp_seq=1 ttl=49 time=25.7 ms
64 bytes from 72.30.35.9: icmp_seq=2 ttl=49 time=25.7 ms

--- 72.30.35.9 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms 
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 25.704/25.724/25.745/0.161 ms
```

This indicates from server X, I can somehow connecting to outside/internet

```
user@reporter:/etc/network$ ping 8.8.8.8 #ping Google IP, does not work
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 6040ms

user@reporter:/etc/network$ ping 8.8.4.4 #ping another Google IP, works. Don't know why
PING 8.8.4.4 (8.8.4.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.4.4: icmp_seq=1 ttl=50 time=12.8 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.4.4: icmp_seq=2 ttl=50 time=12.7 ms

--- 8.8.4.4 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 12.719/12.768/12.817/0.049 ms
```

I think I've set the networking files like "interfaces" correctly on server X, like below

```
user@reporter:/etc/network$ more interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
# The primary network interface
auto eno1
iface eno1 inet static
address 192.168.2.10 -------------Note: this is the internal IP of the server I'm on now
gateway 192.168.2.1 -------------Note: this is the internal IP of the router
netmask 255.255.255.0
dns-nameservers 127.0.0.1 --------------Note: I also tried 72.30.35.9, 8.8.4.4, 8.8.8.8, and the IP my client gave. Every time I change the IP here. I issue command "sudo service networking restart" But all IPs have the same results: cannot ping www.yahoo.com but positive for 72.30.35.9
```

And the /etc/resolv.conf file looks like

```
# Dynamic ..... comment line
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

HOWEVER I CANNOT PING BY DOMAIN NAME

```
user@reporter:/etc/network$ ping www.yahoo.com 
ping: unknown host www.yahoo.com
user@reporter:/etc/network$ ping www.google.com
ping: unknown host www.google.com
user@reporter:~/Documents/tony/temp$ wget www.yahoo.com
--2019-05-23 20:29:51--  http://www.yahoo.com/
Resolving www.yahoo.com (www.yahoo.com)... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘www.yahoo.com’

user@reporter:~/Documents/tony/temp$ wget 8.8.4.4 # did not get anything, but output indicating "Connecting"
--2019-05-23 20:30:21--  http://8.8.4.4/
Connecting to 8.8.4.4:80... ^C
```

Not sure if the router setting has any problem, but since I can ping IP, I guess it's more at the level of the server (Ubuntu v16.04).

Edit 05/24/2019
Now on my router, I can ping www.yahoo.com successfully, which means the problem is at the server level.

Thanks a lot!

Edit:
After a couple of days, I can now ping www.yahoo.com from my server. However how the problem is solved, I have NO IDEA! Probably it takes time to configure the setting? Or my client change some settings at their end......

Comment: Problem solved. After a couple of days, I can now ping www.yahoo.com from my server. However how the problem is solved, I have NO IDEA! Probably it takes time to configure the setting? Or my client change some settings at their end......